# How to solve "Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string"

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, node-sass

My CLI shows an error after I cloned a [Vue project](https://github.com/mhsiungw/twitter-front-end), run `npm install` and run `npm run serve`

the error shown:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     21:50:02

 error  in ./src/components/Trends.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Trends.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-437 15:3-20:5 16:22-445
 @ ./src/components/Trends.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/components/Trends.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/MainPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/MainPage.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/views/MainPage.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.20.10.3:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

so I thought there might be something wrong with node.scss and tried reinstalling it, but after I run `nom install node-scss`, it failed and showed an error:

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /Users/NEIL/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/NEIL/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.10.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.16
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.10.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.10.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:65549) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/NEIL/.node-gyp/16.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/NEIL/.node-gyp/16.10.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/NEIL/.node-gyp/16.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/NEIL/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node" "/Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/NEIL/Desktop/twitter-front-end/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/NEIL/.npm/_logs/2021-11-29T14_23_41_479Z-debug.log
```

I've tried run `npm uninstall node-sass` and `npm install node-sass`.
Also,

I've also tried downgrading the version of my node to 14.18.1.

Both ways didn't work.

I was wondering why this happened and would appreciate any help.
Thanks!!

Comment: Is your npm up to date ? Have you tried to use yarn as recommanded in the readme.md of your project ?

Comment: I faced with same issue, please share solution if you found.